# OSB 12c - Error 404 WSDL

Tags: weblogic12c, osb

I have a project deployed on OSB 12.2.1.2.0 and I cannot access the wsdl inside this project. I'm seeing the wsdl accessing by sbconsole and I'm trying to access using this configuration: 
http://host:port/project_name/wsdl_folder/wsdl_name?wsdl. 
Is it not possible to access a wsdl inside a folder in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access a simple wsdl inside a folder on a project on OSB. I've deployed on outside the folder and everything worked fine \o/.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the WSDL of the webservice with following URL:

```
http://host:port/webservice_endpoint?WSDL
```

For example:

Webservice: 
    http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx

WSDL of webservice: 
    http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?WSDL